# Crash: java.lang.RuntimeException android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)

Tags: android

TermsNConditionsActivity.java @ Line #60, I am not able to reproduce this issue aging

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // load the layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tnc); // Line #60 
}
```

**Crash log**

```
Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.RuntimeException
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:305)
android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1944)
com.acision.mobile.smartsms.TermsNConditionsActivity.onCreate(TermsNConditionsActivity.java:60)
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteIn
```

**activity_tnc.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_white_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/call_Support"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        layout="@layout/support_call_view"
         />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/call_Support"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/terms_and_conditions_margins" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_above="@+id/acceptButton"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/acceptButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/orange_btn_sel_complete"
            android:text="@string/accept"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/accept_btn_text" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**support_call_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/call_support_con"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/support_call_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".04" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".96"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/call_support_txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/call_supprt_txt_service_scrn"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/call_support_text_size" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/call_support_num"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text="@string/call_support_num"
                android:textColor="@color/support_call_num_clr"
                android:textSize="@dimen/call_support_text_size" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/help_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/help_btn_selector_en" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cross_img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:src="@drawable/cross_img_selector" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's problem from your `activity_tnc.xml` post it please

Comment: Posting... Ok agreed but why it is not reproducible ?

Comment: Because there's an error on your `Layout` then when it call `setContentView` and read your xml file it returns an error... just post it

Comment: Added please have a look thank you,

Comment: `RelativeLayout` don't have any `orientation` attribute so you can remove it

Comment: Can you post `support_call_view`?

Comment: removed orientation, added  support_call_view.xml, please have a look again

Comment: double check your color values

Comment: I've addapted it on my test project and it doesn't crash... so maybe the problem is in your java code...

Comment: I have already posted my java code, then you was told me that error in xml. I have alos mention it is not reproducible.